# printf: how to explain corrupted result

Tags: c, linux, 64-bit, printf, calling-convention

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        double resd = 0.000116;
        long long resi = 0;

        printf("%lld %f %lld %f\n", resd, resd, resi, resi);
        return 0;
}
```

gives (Linux, gcc, x64)

```
0 0.000116 0 0.000116
             ^^^^^^^^ odd, since the memory for resi is zeroed
```

Actually, compiled with g++ it gives random results instead of the second 0.

I understand I gave invalid specifiers to `printf` and that it triggers <del>unspecified</del> undefined behavior, but I wonder why this specific corruption occurs, since `long long` and `double` have the same size.

Comment: `it triggers unspecified behavior` ... nuff said :P

Comment: @pmg: The behavior is *undefined*, not unspecified (7.19.6.1.9).  There is a difference.

Comment: @Martin: It can't be explained by the standard, but it can still be explained; the behavior is undefined, not non-deterministic.  It is a real question, just not about the C language.

Comment: @Martin I added the tags calling-convention and x64. This is actually what this question is about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get the same results as you do on my machine (Mac OS X, so AMD/Linux ABI).  The floating point parameters are passed in XMM registers and the integer parameters in integer registers.  When `printf` grabs them using `va_arg`, it pulls from XMM when it sees the `%f` format, and from the other registers when it sees `%lld`.  Here's the disassembly for your program as compiled (`-O0`) on my machine:

```
 1 _main:
 2   pushq   %rbp
 3   movq    %rsp,%rbp
 4   subq    $0x20,%rsp
 5   movq    $0x3f1e68a0d349be90,%rax
 6   move    %rax,0xf8(%rbp)
 7   movq    $0x00000000,0xf0(%rbp)
 8   movq    0xf0(%rbp),%rdx
 9   movq    0xf0(%rbp),%rsi
10   movsd   0xf8(%rbp),%xmm0
11   movq    0xf8(%rbp),%rax
12   movapd  %xmm0,%xmm1
13   movq    %rax,0xe8(%rbp)
14   movsd   0xe8(%rbp),%xmm0
15   lea     0x0000001d(%rip),%rdi
16   movl    $0x00000002,%eax
17   callq   0x100000f22    ; symbol stub for: _printf
18   movl    $0x00000000,%eax
19   leave
20   ret
```

There you can see what's going on - the format string is passed in `%rdi`, then your parameters are passed (in order) in:  `%xmm0`, `%xmm1`, `%rsi`, and `%rdx`.  When `printf`
gets them, it pops them off in a different order (the order specified in your format string).  That means it pops them:  `%rsi`, `%xmm0`, `%rdx`, `%xmm1`, giving the results you see.  The `2` in `%eax` is to indicate the number of floating point arguments passed.

Edit:

Here's an optimized version - in this case the shorter code might be easier to understand.  The explanation is the same as above, but with a little less boilerplate noise.  The floating point value is loaded by the `movsd` on line 4.

```
 1 _main:
 2    pushq   %rbp
 3    movq    %rsp,%rbp
 4    movsd   0x00000038(%rip),%xmm0
 5    xorl    %edx,%edx
 6    xorl    %esi,%esi
 7    movaps  %xmm0,%xmm1
 8    leaq    0x00000018(%rip),%rdi
 9    movb    $0x02,%al
10    callq   0x100000f18   ; symbol stub for: _printf
11    xorl    %eax,%eax
12    leave
13    ret
```

Answer (score 10):

It's because under the `x86_64` C calling conventions on your platform, the first two floating-point arguments are passed in `xmm0` and `xmm1`, and the first two integer arguments are passed in GPRs (`rsi` and `rdx` if you're on Linux or OS X), regardless of the order in which they appear.

You're confused because you're expecting that the parameters are passed in memory; they aren't.

Answer (score 2):

- The first number should be a high value since you're passing in a double as an integer. It should be %f.
- What's with the period after the "0" in "resi"? That will turn it into a double, so you're trying to load a double into an integer. That should give you a compiler warning.
- Some implementations might be register-based, so since you're messing up the argument types, it gets confused.

What platform are you compiling on? Windows?

Did you look at the disassembly to see what it actually pushes on the stack? Does it even push them on the stack, or use registers?

Comment: The `%f` format specifier to `printf` is for a double, not a float (this is different from `scanf`); floating point arguments to va_arg functions are implicitly promoted to double.  `%Lf` is for long double.

Comment: I wrote the period accidentally and then removed it (it shouldn't matter anyway). This is Linux, amd64 , compiled with gcc. (the downvote wasn't mine).